# Tcl: How costly is the conversion of a list into a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, tcl

Donal Fellows gave a comprehensive answer to one of my questions on Tcl dictionaries (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67356051/3852630), but it is still not clear to me how much effort is internally required in converting a list to a dictionary.

I have a either a dictionary or a list, and both are used as elements in some list. Both are accessed with `dict get` later:

```
# dict as list element
set l1 [list first second [dict create one 111 two 222 three 333]]
puts [tcl::unsupported::representation [lindex $l1 2]]
puts [dict get [lindex $l1 2] two]

# list as list element, but used as dictionary
set l2 [list first second [list one 111 two 222 three 333]]
puts [tcl::unsupported::representation [lindex $l2 2]]
puts [dict get [lindex $l2 2] two]
```

Here's the output:

```
value is a dict with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0x556ef4f61980, internal representation 0x556ef4f56cc0:(nil), no string representation
222
value is a list with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0x556ef4f61740, internal representation 0x556ef4f7c580:(nil), no string representation
222
```

So the element with index 2 is actually a `dict` in `l1`, and a `list` in `l2`. When I access this element with `dict get`, how much effort is internally required to convert the `list` element in `l2` to a `dict` before it can be consulted? Or phrased differently, does it make a difference whether the list element is a `dict` or a `list` with respect to the runtime of `dict get`?